# Pegman has disappeared from my map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

For as long as I can remember, the street view pegman has appeared on my map.  Today, I noticed that he doesn't appear (although if you know where to mouse over to grab him, you can still get a streetview happening).  My zoom control has similarly disappeared (but is still there if you know where to mouse for it) but not on mobile devices where it seems to display just fine.

My first guess is that this is a bug in the Maps API that's been introduced recently.  But specifying `v=3.4` in the URL for the API doesn't correct the issue.

Am I doing something wrong?  If not, is there a workaround?

Here's how I create the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lat=<?php echo $lat; ?>;
var lon=<?php echo $lon; ?>;
var initialZoom=<?php echo $initialZoom; ?>;
var mapTypeId = 'Custom Map';
var mapStyle = [{featureType:"administrative", elementType:"all", stylers:[{hue:"#dae6c3"},{saturation:22},{lightness:-5}]}, 
                {featureType:"landscape", elementType:"all", stylers:[{hue:"#dae6c3"},{saturation:16},{lightness:-7}]},
                {featureType:"road", elementType:"geometry", stylers:[{hue:"#ffffff"},{saturation:-100},{lightness:100}]}];
var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyle);

var mapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256,256),
    getTileUrl: function(coord,zoom) {
        return "img/tiles/"+zoom+"/"+coord.x+"/"+coord.y+".png";
    }
});
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
        {center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
         mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         zoom:initialZoom,
         mapTypeControl:false});
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, mapType);

map.mapTypes.set(mapTypeId, styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId(mapTypeId);
</script>
```

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RECk2/2/

Can you fork the fiddle and update it until it demonstrates the problem you are having?

Comment: Mission accomplished via jsfiddle fiddling.  Thanks for setting that up.  I had a relatively recent CSS rule addition that was messing up the pegman control display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had recently added this CSS rule which was causing the problem:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%; 
}
```

Removing that rule fixed the problem.