# Pegman is fuzzed out

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the StreetViewPanoramio functionality in the Google Maps Javascript API v3, an I'm not able to get the Street View Controls to work.  At first I thought the Pegman was not showing up, then I realized it was showing as a fuzzed out square.  And the street view controls don't show on the map.  Both the Map and the StreetView work otherwise - the both load and display the correct location.  I'm currently testing this out in Chrome.

I have a map and a streetview panoramio side-by-side, and I'm trying to follow the example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple).  I know the fuzzy square is the pegman because I can grab it and move it around, and it behaves like the pegman should.  I also have a marker on the map that behaves as expected.

[image: The big fuzzy square on the left edge of the map is the pegman]

My HTML is pretty simple:

```
<div class="maps-area">
    <div id="mapCanvas"/>
    <div id="streetViewCanvas"/>
</div>
```

And my Javascript is almost the same as the examples:

```
//note: center is a valid google.maps.LatLng object.
//Setup the panoramio
var panoOptions = {
  position: center,
  pov: {
    heading: 0,
    pitch: 10
  }
};

var svElement = document.getElementById("streetViewCanvas");
_panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(svElement, panoOptions);

//Setup the map
var mapOptions = {
  center: center,
  zoom: 12,
  streetViewControl: true,
  streetView: _panorama,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);
```

Comment: max-width: none; on the map canvas.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis - setting max-width: none; on the canvas didn't fix it, but it lead me in the right direction, and with the help of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101473/pegman-has-disappeared-from-my-map), I removed the max-width: 100% from Bootstrap's `img` style, and it did solve it.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101473/pegman-has-disappeared-from-my-map) and Dan's comment above, I was able to track down the problem to the `max-width`: 100% style being applied to images on the map.

Bootstrap.css defines this style for `img`:

```
img {
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

which was causing the problem.  I assigned a `map-canvas` class to my mapCanvas element, and then created this style to override Bootstrap's style:

```
.map-canvas img{
    max-width: none;
}
```

and the streetview controls and pegman rendered correctly.